The question about some behaviors of a.a.a.a in lua
I was just following the practice in the book.
Which is sth like:
a = {}
a.a = a

a.a.a.a = 3

It behaves normally at begin, until i found that
it's a.a == 3 , but not a == 3
could someone just tell me why
my env:
Linux 6.1.0-18-amd64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Debian 6.1.76-1 (2024-02-01) x86_64 GNU/Linux
Lua 5.4.4  Copyright (C) 1994-2022 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
a = {}
a.a = a
print(a.a.a.a)

a.a.a.a = 3
print(a)
print(a.a)
print(a.a.a)
print(a.a.a.a)

and it's output is
table: 0x562c8c447fc0
table: 0x562c8c447fc0
3
lua5.4: main.lua:37: attempt to index a number value (field 'a')
stack traceback:
        main.lua:37: in main chunk
        [C]: in ?


a.a is sugar syntax for a['a'] you are indexing the table a with the string 'a' as the key so all you have done is turned a table that had a self reference into a = { a = 3 }

You are doing essentially this (I renamed the keys and variables to make the distinction clearer):
local b = {}
local a = {
    value = b
}

a.value = 3

print(b)

Why would setting a.value change b? You can't change local variables like that. So even though it might seem that you can alter a (and more precisely in this case, what a is 'pointing to', as tables behave like references to something), you are actually only altering the contents of the table that you store a reference to in a.

thanks, this answers my question very well

If it is the answer you are seeking for, you can accecpt it by clicking on the checkmark next to it. This marks this question as solved for others.
